# Firebase functions - remove parent

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly.

I'd like to remove the parent of a node if the variable parameter within the node is true..

This is what I have:

```
exports.removePost = functions.database
.ref('posts/{locationId}/{postId}/score')
.onUpdate(async snapshot => {

const score = snapshot.after.val();

if(score < -4)
  return false;
if(score >= -4)
  return snapshot.ref.parent().remove();

return false;
});
```

So `score` is an integer and if it is equal to or greater than -4 `onUpdate` I'd like to remove the parent, so `{postId}`.

I'm guessing this is possible. But when I try to deploy the code above it says that `ref does not exist on type 'Change<DataSnapshot>'.`

Why does it say that?

Also, as a side question -- if I set the firebase security rules so that only a user with the same `uid` as the `postId`'s `uid`, will the above code still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting the first argument to your onUpdate handler function to be DataSnapshot object, but it is not.  The first argument to [onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onUpdate) and [onWrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite) handler function is a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object with `before` and `after` fields that describe the contents of the database at the trigger location before and the change that triggered it.  These fields are [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot) objects with a `ref` field.

If you want the ref of the location that changed, try this instead:

```
exports.removePost = functions.database
.ref('posts/{locationId}/{postId}/score')
.onUpdate(async change => {

    const score = change.after.val();

    if (score < -4) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return change.after.ref.parent.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I thought that would work, I got an error though: `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Reference' has no compatible call signatures.` it's referring to the `return change..` line. any idea?

Comment: Actually, `parent` is a property, not a method.  Edited.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#parent

Comment: Hmm, it's actually removing the post regardless of what `score` is... would you know why perhaps? the `score` is stored as a variable so it should work, but it's not. As soon as `score` changes it removes the parent..

Comment: Log the value of `score` and see if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad. I mixed up the negative values and greater than, forgetting that -4 was greater than -5 lol